Is my g37 supposed to be making these noises?
So I opened my engine bay when the car was on and I heard this noise. I don’t know how to describe it, but it sounds kind of weird.
I do not know much about engines so I don’t know if this is normal or not.
I recorded a video, is there something wrong with my car? I am sorry if I come across as stupid.
here is the video

Have you checked your oil level? Are you using the right oil? I'm hearing a bit of valvetrain noise. What year is your G? How many miles on it? Regular maintenance?
